# Solr range gap progressive

Tags: solr, range, progressive

Is there a way of having ranges (price) with a progressive gap, rather than a fixed one?

Like this:

0-100
100-150
150-250
250-400
400-600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

> Gaps can also be variable width by passing in a comma separated list of the gap size to be used.

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-The%7B%7Bfacet.range.gap%7D%7DParameter).